# Is there a Python implementation of Twitter's Snowflake UUID generator?

Tags: python, uuid

I need a sequential UUID generator like Twitter's Snowflake - https://github.com/twitter/snowflake/ .

But Snowflake is implemented in Scala, and I'm finding a similar project in the Python world, not Scala.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OMG, I found this : https://github.com/erans/pysnowflake

Answer (score 1):

You may find what you need in the [Python  uuid module](http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html)

Comment: Thank you for comment. But I don't think python uuid gives same or similar result that I want. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713873/is-python-uuid1-sequential-as-timestamps

Comment: @lqez Are you aware that the current versions of Python allow you to provide a key function for ordering? If you use `uuid1()` or another function that includes the timestamp to create your UUIDs, you should be able to include `key=lambda id: id.time` or `key=operator.attrgetter('time')` in the arguments to whatever ordering system you're using and have no problem at all. And if all else fails and you're using Python 3.2, you can subclass `uuid.UUID` and use [`functools.total_ordering()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to set it up.

Comment: (Of course, you can still do the subclassing with earlier versions of Python, it would just take a bit more code as you'd have to define all the comparison functions manually.)